On-premise Active Directory security tab - how to get Inherited from column using PowerShell?
I'm trying to create Active Directory permission report and wanted to get the information available in the 'dsa.msc' gui snap-in using PowerShell.
This is the data I am after:
User object - properties - security - advanced

Does anyone know how to get the 'Inherited from' column using PowerShell?
I managed to get rest of the columns using
(Get-Acl "AD:\$($UserDN)").Access

but not sure how to get this column.
Some help appreciated ...thanks

Usually you'd "walk backwards" up the tree until you find the node that defines the permission explicitly. So if you want to find out where "CN=A,OU=B,OU=C,OU=D,DC=E" inherited a given rule, first check the ACL on OU=B, then OU=C, then OU=D, until you find that particular rule

thanks Mathias .. searching i did so far did not pick up any code that's available, although there are scripts to report on this info, this field is missing. if anyone` done this before and could share some code samples, appropriated ..

Is the user that you want know the inheritance information a member of a protected group? Then this object's permissions are determined via another process  (AdminSDHolder)  and the object's permissions are not inherited anyway. Details are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory
